# sql server 2008, cannot use order by in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

here's my sql server 2008 stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetSharedSmoothies]
    @Page INT ,
    @Status INT ,
    @ItemPerPage INT
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @X INT 
        DECLARE @Y INT

        SET @X = ( @Page - 1 ) * @ItemPerPage
        SET @Y = @Page * @ItemPerPage


        SELECT  *
        FROM    ( SELECT    S.* ,
                            U.Avatar ,
                            U.Displayname ,
                            ( SELECT    COUNT(Id)
                              FROM      Vote
                              WHERE     Vote.SmoothieId = S.Id
                            ) AS Votes ,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY S.Id ) rownum
                  FROM      dbo.Smoothie AS S
                            INNER JOIN dbo.[User] AS U ON S.UserId = U.Id
                  WHERE     S.IsPublic = 1
                            AND S.Status = 3
                            AND S.UserId > 0
                  -- ORDER BY  S.CreatedDate DESC
                ) seq
        WHERE   seq.rownum BETWEEN @X AND @Y
        ORDER BY seq.rownum
    END
```

in my code, you will see I comment out the order by

```
 -- ORDER BY  S.CreatedDate DESC
```

because order by will not work in subquery. i need to show the lastest one on the top.  is there a way I can use order by in my code?

Comment: +1 for very nicely formatted code and very clearly worded question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add `S.CreatedDate` within the `Row_NUMBER()`

`ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY S.Id ORDER BY S.CreatedDate DESC) AS RowNum`

Comment: thanks alot, just one small correction. should be ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY S.Id DESC) rownum

Comment: @feelexit Glad you exprimented and got it worked :) I got the impressions you wanted to have `partition over ID` and `order by CreatedDate` ;)

Answer (score 3):

That's right. It is not allowed, because it will do nothing.

Having the latest one at the top in the subquery will do **nothing** to the result set using the subquery.

Add the needed column to the result set `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER BY seq.CreatedDate DESC, seq.rownum
```

Or:

```
ORDER BY seq.rownum, seq.CreatedDate DESC
```